# BLE Shield used for ANCS iPhone

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino

I have a http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/.

I successfully tested the Chat example and i have sent a message from iPhone to Arduino.

Now i want to test the ANCS functionality. From what i heard, the iPhone must be the Peripheral and BLE Shield must connect to ANCS service and then it will receive notifications.

Is it possible to discover and connect to bluetooth devices using BLE Shield? How?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to discover and connect to bluetooth devices using BLE Shield?

yes it is possible! I'm currently writing an article and I'm also about to publish a library that handles ANCS notifications. It's way more complicated than only running the Chat example, though.

> How?

To access the ANCS, here are the key things to do:

- open nRFGoStudio

  - add the ANCS services into the pipe definition
  - force bonding to access the services
  - and generate the new `services.h`
- in your code

  - when bonding is done shutdown and restart the BLE radio
  - wait until the ANCS pipes are opened
  - when they all are opened, subscribe to the ANCS Notification Source

to get more details, and a working library, please have a look at the following article I wrote:

- http://i.got.nothing.to/code/on/avr-for-ble-and-ios

and the library:

- https://github.com/guyzmo/avr_nrf_ancs_library

HTH

Comment: hope you'll like the article :-)

Comment: Cool, man! But I have a few questions. Did you start from a template? Which one? Did you use the proximity template? Because your Nrfgo screenshot shows different services that the proximity templates has.

Do you must have an iOS App or you have to connect from Settings or it will just connect?

In NRFgo in Gap Settings what did you check and what didn't you check?

Comment: I did indeed start with the proximity template (it's written in the article). The GAP settings are mostly the same as Proximity's defaults, and you can use my .xml profile [here](https://github.com/guyzmo/avr_nrf_ancs_library/blob/master/ble_lib/nrf8001_ancs.xml), but honestly, the GAP settings are mostly try and err to build.

Comment: I've done all my BLE projects using an iOS app, lightblue or custom made, and having the iOS App trying to connect to one characteristic of the device to force the bonding. I guess it could be possible to start the bonding from the device by accessing a publicly advertised characteristic on iOS side, but I'm not sure if that'd work.

Comment: N.B.: I just changed the URL scheme of my blog, sorry for the dead links

Comment: I did it yesterday, thanks mate! I'm curious if you can access the ANCS without bonding. I have read that if you advertise a specific packet you can connect without bonding. Working on it... :) Anyways, thanks and good job! :)

Comment: Well, I'd be curious to see where you read that, because it's not documented by Apple *AT ALL* and the Nordic Engineers were pretty clear on that point: to access the ANCS you *shall* be bonded. Which makes sense, there is personal informations in the notifications that you do not want to broadcast to the first BLE device sniffing around. If you can advertise a specific packet that can enable the ANCS without bonding, then it can be considered as a security hole!

Comment: Here: http://mbientlab.com/blog/ancs-on-ti2541-in-an-afternoon/ "You can either advertise a specific payload or require your devices to bond. This is required or your iOS device will not allow you to read and write the ANCS service characteristics. You can check Apple forums for information on the specific payload you can use to bypass the bonding process."

Comment: uhuh... the guy says you can use a specific payload but does not tell about it, or give a link to the forum.

Comment: @zmo, very interested in this exact topic with the exact hardware, but your links are dead again.  Even googling the title points to the same place, but it's still down.  Care to repost, or let us know when your server will be back up?  Thanks!

Comment: @MarqueIV thank you for the notification, situation solved ;-)

Comment: Hi again @zmo, I deleted my old comments.  Any chance you can be contacted to answer a few questions about your library? We'd be willing to pay you for your time.  Shouldn't be more than an hour or two but can go longer if you're interested.  Lemme know.